# Style shiny variable with css tags

Tags: r, shiny

How do I style a variable in a shiny app with custom css?

I am working through the beginner's tutorial and I wish to place emphasis on  a variable in this code:

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output){
    output$text1 <- renderText({
        paste("you have selected ",  input$var, " from the dropdown selector")
    })

    output$text2 <- renderText({
        paste("You have selected the range", input$range[1], 'to', input$range[2])
    })


})
```

I want to place emphasis on `input$var` and I have tried `em(input$var)` to no avail.

Anyone know the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would work (not tested code, but it's the right idea)

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    "you have selected",
    em(textOutput("text1")),
    "from the dropdown selector"
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$text1 <- renderText({ input$var })
}
```

Or, if you really want to do all the rendering on the server side, then you could use `uiOutput`+`renderUI` instead of text

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    uiOutput("text1")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$text1 <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      "you have selected",
      em(input$var),
      "from the dropdown selector"
    )
  })
}
```